# NullPointerException with StreamTokenizer

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Given a `StringBuilder` of this form:

```
data_driven: [data-driven, web economy, leading, Fortune 500, knowledge-driven, pyramid-based, market-driven, capital-based, profit-driven, market-focused, bottom-line focused, new economy, Brazilian, European ], 
market_leaders: [market leaders, corporations, eCompanies, eBusinesses, web 2.0 corporations, virtual companies, virtual businesses, virtual eBusinesses, virtual eMonopolies, information workers ]
```

I need to create a list out of the words inside the brackets after a given token (such as `data_driven` or `market_leaders`).

Here is my code:

```
public List<String> getPhrases(StringBuilder fileContent, String token) {
StringReader reader = new StringReader(fileContent.toString());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);  
StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(br);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
          while (tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
            if (tokenizer.sval.equals(token)) {
              tokenizer.nextToken();  // skip the ":"
              tokenizer.nextToken(); // skip the "["
              do {
                tokenizer.nextToken();  // go to the first phrase
                String stuff = tokenizer.sval;
                list.add(stuff);
              } while (tokenizer.nextToken() == ',');
              break;
            }
          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

When I call the method with my `StringBuilder` and token as parameters, I get a `NullPointerException` at the line:

```
if (tokenizer.sval.equals(token)) {
```

I have printed out my `StringBuilder` and it *does* have the token I have used when calling the method.

Does anyone see a reason why I would be getting this exception?

Comment: this is a very problematic way to do this.  You keep reading tokens with nextToken() and if they are not what you think they are being thrown away!  Look at `while (tokenizer.nextToken() == ',');`  When it is NOT a comma, you lose whether it was!  Seems like you want to read this into a string variable, and then test/manipulate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably take a different approach to this problem, I would first isolate the outer token; then I would isolate the contents of the "[" and "]" and then I would use a `StringTokenizer` that is, I would use this approach

```
// Static level, because it doesn't depend on outside state.
public static List<String> getPhrases(
    StringBuilder fileContent, String token) {
  // An output List.
  List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
  final int p1 = fileContent.indexOf(token);
  if (p1 >= 0) { // we have a "token"
    int pos1 = fileContent.indexOf("[", p1 + 1);
    if (pos1 >= 0) { // we have an open "["
      int pos2 = fileContent.indexOf("]", pos1 + 1);
      if (pos2 >= 0) { // we have a closing "]"
        String str = fileContent.substring(pos1 + 1,
            pos2);
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(
            str, ","); // Now use a Tokenizer.
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
          String s = st.nextToken();
          if (s != null) { // Don't trim a null!
            al.add(s.trim());
          } else { // You may not want this...
            al.add("");
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // Return that output List.
  return al;
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! This works very well, thank you for your help and useful comments.